# Property ref not found on object of type 'ViewController'?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I'm following firebase tutorial for FB login.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
   [super viewDidLoad];
     // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
     // Align the button in the center horizontally


   Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://MYURL.com"];
    // Open a session showing the user the login UI
      [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:@[@"public_profile"] allowLoginUI:YES
      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {

         if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Facebook login failed. Error: %@", error);
            } else if (state == FBSessionStateOpen) {
                  NSString *accessToken = session.accessTokenData.accessToken;
                  [self.ref authWithOAuthProvider:@"facebook" token:accessToken
                  withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAuthData *authData) {

                   if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Login failed. %@", error);
                                                      } else {
                        NSLog(@"Logged in! %@", authData);
                                                      }
                              }];
                         }
                    }];
```

There is an error occur in the line:

```
[self.ref authWithOAuthProvider:@"facebook" token:accessToken
              withCompletionBlock:^(NSError *error, FAuthData *authData)
```

"Property ref not found on object of type 'ViewController'"

when I declare it on the top of the file in section.

```
@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) Firebase* ref;

@end
```

the error disappear and the warning appears on this line of code

```
Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://sizzling-inferno-8395.firebaseio.com"];
```

it says "Unused Entity Issue, Unused variable 'ref'"

Why? how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In case first you have declared the variable "`ref`" locally and thus it is not part of "`class`" hence self will not work.

In case two you have declared variable "`ref`" at class level and hence it can be and should be referred as "`self.ref`".

You are getting warning as you are not using the local variable and using the class member "`self.ref`".

Comment: I have tried to do this too:
interface ViewController ()
property (weak, nonatomic) Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com"];
end

and it is still doesn't work. How can I declared in class level and also make it work like this: Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://<YOUR-FIREBASE>.firebaseio.com"]; ?

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you're creating a ref locally. Instead of this:

`Firebase *ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://MYURL.com"];`

Put:

`self.ref = [[Firebase alloc] initWithUrl:@"https://MYURL.com"];`

This will set it on your view controller instead of creating a new local variable. If you really want to have a local `ref` variable, you can do it on the next line with:

`Firebase *ref = self.ref;`

Also, not sure if you declared your Firebase property as weak to avoid a retain cycle, but you probably want to declare it as strong so that ARC doesn't randomly decide to reclaim it while the ViewController is still being used.

`@property (strong, nonatomic) Firebase* ref;`